# Change Tiny MCE Account Owner

Tags: tinymce

I can't edit the email in the Account Settings for Tiny MCE and need to change the login information as I am leaving the company. Is there any way to do this through the website or is there a support email?

Answer (score 1):

Although it states commercial users only, I submitted through the support link:  https://support.tiny.cloud/hc/en-us